# How to show success messages on magento 2x home page externally redirect url?

Tags: redirect, netsuite

In Magento 2.x form use in `<iframe src="forms.netsuite.com ">` after submitting from netsuite return/redirect to home-page-url/?whence=

I need to show success message in home page:

```
<div class="page messages"> </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your submit, controller assigns messageManager like below.

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('This is a success message.'));
```

Then you need to assign a placeholder for the message through frontend layout xml used in the module as given below inside the `<body>` tag.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Note:** If you are using ajax submit the form it might not work.

I hope it helps!

Comment: submit plus all form come from 3rd party netsuite as like as Zoho form in iframe , when submit form got netsuite & redirect to home page as home-page-url/?whence= now need to show massage

Comment: Have you stored value in the database of this form? have you used API to integrate third-party form?

Comment: If possible then share your code what you have done for display form, so based on that give a solution.

Comment: not stored value on my db, Its totally external form come via ifram

Comment: plz check again i upload img